# How can I return a list from view to controller in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I like to do one simple control for day transactions. 
That need to show me how much transaction we have this day (close or open trans) and when the manager click the number of transaction I would like to send all this list of transactions into a nice table. 
But I can't find the way to do it. Not even across the web.

here is my try but nothing.
I am open for suggestion =)

Here is my **ViewModel**

```
public class SIMcontrolsViewModel
{

    public DTControls DTransactionControl { get; set; }
}  
public class DTControls
{
    public DateTime TDate { get; set; }

    public int NumOfTransaction { get; set; }
    public List<SIMsale> SIMsaleList { get; set; }

    public DTControls()
    {
        SIMsaleList = new List<SIMsale>();
    }
}
```

the **Controller** look like I fill all the data and I sent it to view

```
    [AdminAuthorization]
    public ActionResult DateTransactionsControl(DateTime? date)
    {
        SIMcontrolsViewModel vm = new SIMcontrolsViewModel();
        vm.DTransactionControl = new DTControls();
        if (!date.HasValue)
            date = DateTime.Now;//.Today;
        vm.DTransactionControl.TDate = date.Value;
        try
        {
            using (CompanyContext db = new CompanyContext())
            {
                var saleLst = db.SIMsales.ToList();

                foreach (var sale in saleLst)
                {
                    if (..)
                        vm.DTransactionControl.SIMsaleList.Add(sale);

                }
                var tCount = vm.DTransactionControl.SIMsaleList.Count;
                vm.DTransactionControl.NumOfTransaction = tCount;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {..}
        return View(vm); 
    }
```

Now on my **View** I try to send this list from this `@Html.ActionLink` like we can see here.

```
@model oCc.IPToGo.ViewModel.SIMcontrolsViewModel


<fieldset>
      <table border="0" class="display">
            <thead>
                <tr>            
                   <th style="width:100px">Date</th>
            <th style="width:100px">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DTransactionControl.NumOfTransaction)</th>                
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr style="text-align: center">
            <td>@Model.DTransactionControl.TDate.ToShortDateString()</td>
            @if (Model.DTransactionControl.NumOfTransaction != 0)
            {
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink(Model.DTransactionControl.NumOfTransaction.ToString(), "../SIMsale/",
                                                    new { sell = Model.DTransactionControl.SIMsaleList },
                                                    new { style = "font-weight: bold; color: Highlight" })
                </td>      

            }
            else
            {
                <td style="color:red">0</td>
            }
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
 </fieldset>
```

The **problem** is that the view/controller who supposed to get this list is getting an empty list.

10Q =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply sent the `SIMsales` condition like `sellerId` on your ViewModel and a Hidden field on Razor to keep the data and on pthe post function (on your controller) just retrive all of those `SIMsales` that you count on the Get func.

(I know that was two year before but maybee that can help)

Comment: 10x.. that kind of what i do =))

Answer (score 1):

I would associate an id with the transaction count and pass that back to the controller through an ajax call

```
$.ajax({
 url: "@(Url.Action("Action", "Controller"))",
 type: "POST",
 cache: false,
 async: true,
 data: { id: 'associatedID' },
 success: function (result) {
     $(".Content").html(result);
 }
```

});

create a partial view for displaying the table and on your controller populate and return the partial view using the passed id

```
public PartialViewResult BuildTable(int id){
    Model model = (get results from database for id)
    return PartialView("_Partial", model);
}
```

then put a div on your view with a class of Content (or whatever you want to call it).  Hopefully this helps.